# Chrome extension to filter search results

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have recently been annoyed with the amount of aggregation sites that keep popping up in Google Search results. They offer (to me) nothing useful and obscure the valuable sites. Unfortunately, Google removed their offering to ignore/skip sites in results a while ago. I am starting to work on a Chrome extension to filter these out of search results, and ran into a big of a snag.

The first thing I tried was the `webRequest.onBeforeRequest`, but ran into issues with differences in Manifest v3. I realized that what I am going for might not be possible, and thought I would check.

The only thing I want to be able to do is modify Google Search requests to include a list of excluded sites, using the `-site:<url>` syntax that Google supports. For example, a search for "yargs vs commander" might become "yargs vs commander -site:npmtrends.com", assuming the user had set `npmtrends.com` in the blacklist.

However, I am not sure whether this is possible with Chrome extensions? If it is, will the resulting search display also include the `-site:npmtrends.com` (ie. in browser bar)? If so, could I simply filter it out again at that point (as it will be added again for future requests)?

I have been using `declarativeNetRequest` API work (Manifest v3), coupled with a `redirect` rule. However, while a `regexFilter` like `[?&]q=[^&#]+` and `regexSubstitution` like `\\0+-site%3Anpmtrends.com` does work, it also results in an infinite redirection loop (since condition is always true). Google's regex syntax does not seem to support lookbehinds/lookaheads, significantly limiting possibilities.

It is quite frustrating that Manifest v3 seems to be a step backward in power regarding URL requests, as this would be easy if using JS (since it requires several checks over the whole string)...

Welcoming any feedback/recommendations!

EDIT: Apparently I forgot (to my shame) to include examples/link to my attempts...my apologies! I am unable to update with examples at the moment, but do have a [GitHub link](https://github.com/kendallroth/chrome-search-hide-domains) (for the little value that contains).

Comment: Show code, or it never happened.

Comment: @Dementic Excellent point, my apologies for not including examples previously (had meant to link to repo at very very least).

Comment: declarativeNetRequest might work via its updateDynamicRules API. Your rule would use regexSubstitution so that `[?&]q=[^&#]+` becomes `\\0+-site:foo+-site:bar`

Comment: @wOxxOm I have been experimenting with this but am running into issues with infinite redirects. Since the original `regexFilter` still matches, it will attempt to redirect yet again, appending infinitely.

Comment: I had attempted to resolve this by adding a `&blocked=true` search parameter, but the `regexFilter` does not support the `?` operator apparently? I was trying `"(.*google\\.com\/search\\?q=)(.*)(?<!blocked=true)$"` but kept getting errors...

Comment: Apparently this is not possible in MV3. You can file a feature request on https://crbug.com to add a parameter to declarativeNetRequest like `once` to run a rule just once per request. Meanwhile, a workaround is to use chrome.tabs.onUpdated or chrome.webNavigation API and then do chrome.tabs.update with the new URL. It's quite bad as it mangles the history in the tab.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yeah, I was starting to get the vibe that this simply wasn't possible... Ah well, if only Google also supported the ability to filter out site results via headers (which would be far easier to modify)...